# How to specific binding port for Haskell app ?

Tags: haskell, heroku, haskell-stack

When I run and app using stack, it said

```
$ stack exec duckling-example-exe
no port specified, defaulting to port 8000
Listening on http://0.0.0.0:8000
```

However, I would like to bind the port to $PORT (in order to host on heroku).

How should I do so ?
Sorry about newbie question, but I don't know anything about Haskell yet and can't search for any solution so far.

Comment: I presume, you are using some web framework, like Yesod?

Comment: I am trying to deploy https://github.com/facebook/duckling (no idea about any framework)

Comment: Can you do a `stack exec -- duckling-example-exe --port $PORT` on heroku?

Answer (score 4):

If you cannot do a `stack exec -- duckling-example-exe --port $PORT`,
you have to adapt the source code (a little bit) in `exe/ExampleMain.hs`.

```
import System.Environment (lookupEnv)
...

main :: IO ()
main = do
  setupLogs
  tzs <- loadTimeZoneSeries "/usr/share/zoneinfo/"
  p <- lookupEnv "PORT"
  conf <- commandLineConfig $ maybe defaultConfig (`setPort` defaultConfig)
                                                  (p >>= readMaybe)
  httpServe conf $
    ifTop (writeBS "quack!") <|>
    route
      [ ("targets", method GET targetsHandler)
      , ("parse", method POST $ parseHandler tzs)
      ]
```

The change is not too hard since you can read in the [source code](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/snap-server-1.1.0.0/docs/src/Snap-Http-Server.html#quickHttpServe) how `quickHttpServe` is implemented, adding the port is a bit of a hassle since `setPort :: Int -> Config m a -> Config m a` instead of taking a `Maybe Int` which would have been more convenient here.

Since `lookupEnv` returns a `Maybe String` we can use the monadic bind `>>=` and `readMaybe` to produce a `Maybe Int`.

The function now works as follows:

- if no `PORT` environment variable is set and no command line param is given default value is chosen
- if there is a `--port 8080` this overrides a `PORT=9000`.

Comment: it works pretty well. Have you proposed it in a pull request to FB?

Comment: @PierrOz I didn't think about it - but here I filed a [PR-281](https://github.com/facebook/duckling/pull/281)